# How can I keep my branch up to date with master with git?

Tags: git, github

I have a bug fix in my master, and I also want my branch to get that bug fix.  What `git` command do I use?

Answer (score 244, accepted):

Assuming you're fine with taking all of the changes in master, what you want is:

```
git checkout <my branch>
```

to switch the working tree to your branch; then:

```
git merge master
```

to merge all the changes in master with yours.

Comment: And this just adds the changes from my master into my branch, and leaves the master alone, correct?

Comment: @Nic - This will bring in all the commits from master, not just the bug fix. Be sure if this is what you want to do.

Comment: @Nic - Correct, this does not modify master.

Comment: Might be good to recommend an initial "git checkout master; git pull" to ensure that the local master branch is up-to-date. Usually obvious, but ...

Comment: As a master checkout/merge shortcut, can u just do a "git pull origin master" to pull server master/merge into local checked-out branch?

Answer (score 93):

If your branch is local only and hasn't been pushed to the server, use

```
git rebase master
```

Otherwise, use

```
git merge master
```

Comment: Because it modifies the commit history, and you don't want to push modified search history to the server.

Comment: If you are using a svn repository as your remote repository—via `git svn`—then the `git rebase master` is the way to go, to keep a linear history, which is what svn understands.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the cherry-pick to get the particular bug fix commit(s)

```
$ git checkout branch
$ git cherry-pick bugfix
```

Comment: will the cherry-pick only work if bugfix was a branch that was merged back into master?

Comment: You can cherry-pick, but then after merging the branch into master (when the branch is ready) you will have the bug-fixing commit twice in the history.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the bug fix to be integrated into the branch, `git cherry-pick` the relevant commit(s).